# Bash: range lists like a-b,C,k,m-n,x-y,z

Tags: bash, list, range

How do I get a range-list parameter like "1-6,8,15-20,23,25-28,30" to be parsed/expanded (to "1 2 3 4 5 6 8 15 16 17 18 19 20 23 25 26 27 28 30") with bash? If bash does not work, some other generally available Linux shell coud be considered.

Use case: I have a script that needs to do something with given IDs, and would be (more than) nice to be able to handle "all kinds of" ID lists/ranges in one go. Now my script takes only a single ID range parameter A-B, so if my ID list is not a single contunuous range I need to run the script several times with different range parameters (e.g. "A-B,X-Y" becomes two runs, first "A-B" and then "X-Y").

Short spec for the list parameter:
- a list is one range, or several ranges separated by a comma (other separators also possible)
- a range is A-B (A smaller than B), or a single number X (special case A=B)
- this is numerical/integer ranges/lists, so the possible characters in list are 0-9, "-" and ","

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `bash` function that uses parameter expansion, the `read` command, and the `seq` command to parse and expand a string in the format you gave.

```
parse_range () {
    for range in ${1//,/ }; do
        IFS=- read a b <<< "$range"
        b=${b:-$a}
        seq $a $b
    done
}

for i in $(parse_range 1-6,8,15-20,23,25-28,30); do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to accept this accept this answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ echo {1..6} 8 {15..20} 23 {25..28} 30
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 15 16 17 18 19 20 23 25 26 27 28 30
```

Make sure the you have put space between each argument.

**FYI :** This is called Brace expansion using ranges.

I am using bash 4.2.37

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

For more reading about `Brace Expansion`, click [me](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace)

**Edit:**

You can use variable substitution also:

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:~$ A=1;F=6;H=8;eval echo {$A..$F} $H {15..20} 23 {25..28} 30
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 15 16 17 18 19 20 23 25 26 27 28 30
```

Comment: Unfortunately, brace expansion only works with constants, and it sounds like the question require you to work with the contents of a variable.

Comment: I'll issue the standard warning against `eval`: only use it if you *absolutely trust* the input. Otherwise, you could face something like: `A="};rm -rf /; echo {1"; eval echo {$A..$F}`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use [`seq`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq). If the ranges are separated by whitespace, you can use a for loop

```
for range; do
    case "$range" in
    *-*) for id in $(seq $(echo $range | sed -e 's/-/ /')); do
             do_something $id
         done
         ;;
    *) do_something $range ;;
    esac
done
```

You can call this as

```
bash ranges.sh 1-6 8 15-20 23 25-28 30
```